# Repeating Value using join

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

First image shows the result at `Paid_Amount` column 2nd and 3rd row repeating paid amount while paid one] [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf5iP.png)

2nd image shows `Paid_Amount` exists only once] [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCv1o.png)

**I am using following query, Only one record exists in paid table While Its Repeating 3-time, Please Help me to find out correct result.**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(totalAmount) as TotalSum,
    T_VISIT.dateVisit as Visit,
    T_AMOUNT.amountType as Amount_Type,
    (CASE 
        WHEN T_PAID_AMT_PT.paidAmt IS NOT NULL 
            THEN T_PAID_AMT_PT.paidAmt 
        ELSE 0 END) as Paid_Amount,
    (T_PAID_AMT_PT.paidAmt - SUM(totalAmount)) as Balance 
FROM tblPatientAmountDetails T_AMOUNT 
    INNER JOIN tblVisitDetailsPt T_VISIT 
        ON T_AMOUNT.visitId = T_VISIT.visitId
    INNER JOIN  tblPaidAmountPt T_PAID_AMT_PT 
        ON T_PAID_AMT_PT.visitId = T_VISIT.visitId  
WHERE T_VISIT.regNo = 'OPD0002'  
GROUP BY 
    T_VISIT.dateVisit,
    T_AMOUNT.amountType,
    T_PAID_AMT_PT.paidAmt,
    T_PAID_AMT_PT.balence
```

Comment: please provide the output of the query above and expected output.

Comment: @sqluser - `SELECT DISTINCT` wont help OP because he is already grouping the data based on `T_VISIT.dateVisit,_AMOUNT.amountType,T_PAID_AMT_PT.paidAmt,T_PAID_AMT_PT.balence`

Comment: Please Look Above Images Where I am Getting Problem

Comment: It's not repeating the column. The query you're making is returning 3 _distinct_ rows of results meaning you have no repeating.  Without seeing your data and seeing what you want to achieve - it's rather impossible for us to say what you're doing wrong - but from the look of it, then you likely have some issues with your `VisitId` logic compared to what you have of data.